# Нужен прокси-сервер с возможностью распараллеливания запросов на разные сервера

Tags: запрос, proxy, распараллеливание, прокси

Подскажите, легкий  прокси-сервер  с возможностью распараллеливания запросов на разные сервера.

Comment: А вам нужен forward proxy или reverse proxy? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224664/difference-between-proxy-server-and-reverse-proxy-server

Comment: Спасибо! Нужен  forward proxy. Вот зачем - у меня есть ПОСТ-запрос, я его с помощь. прокси сервера одновременно отправлю на 2 сервера